# Некорректный бинарный поиск в массиве uint64_t

Tags: c, массивы, поиск

Есть код, который осуществляет бинарный поиск по массиву `uint64_t` (сортировку добавлю позже).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define G_SIZE 4096
#define T_EXP 10

uint64_t contains(uint64_t num,uint64_t *arr,uint64_t left,uint64_t right);
uint64_t MontgExp(uint64_t base,uint64_t exp,uint64_t mod);
int main()
{
    uint64_t *cArr, *gArr;
    uint64_t primeNum = 4294967279;
    uint64_t tmp = 0, tmp_base = 2;
    uint64_t res = 0;
    uint64_t T = pow((double)2, (double)T_EXP), i = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    cArr = (uint64_t*)malloc(T * sizeof(uint64_t));
    memset(cArr, 0, T * sizeof(uint64_t));

    gArr = (uint64_t*)malloc(G_SIZE * sizeof(uint64_t));
    memset(gArr, 0, T * sizeof(uint64_t));
    for (i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        cArr[i] = MontgExp(2,rand(),primeNum);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < G_SIZE; i++)
        gArr[i] = rand();

    for (i = 0; i < G_SIZE; i++) {
        if (contains(gArr[i], cArr, 0, T) != -1)
            res++;
    }
    printf("Press any key...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
uint64_t MontgExp(uint64_t base,uint64_t exp,uint64_t mod)
{
    uint64_t res = 1;
    uint64_t base_tmp = base, exp_tmp = exp, mod_tmp = mod;
    base_tmp = base_tmp % mod_tmp;
    while ( exp_tmp > 0) {
        if (exp_tmp & 1)
            res = (res * base_tmp) % mod_tmp;
        exp_tmp = exp_tmp >> 1;
        base_tmp = (base_tmp * base_tmp) % mod_tmp;
    }
    return res;
}
uint64_t contains(uint64_t num,uint64_t *arr,uint64_t left,uint64_t right)
{
    uint64_t middle = 0;
    while (1) {
        middle = (left + right) / 2;
        if (arr[middle] > num)
            right = middle - 1;
        else if (arr[middle] < num)
            left = right + 1;
        else 
            return middle;
    }
    if (left > right)
        return  -1;
}
```

При выполнении программы постоянно выводится `Error!`, в функции поиска `contains` переменная `high` почему-то становится больше размера массива. Не могу понять, почему.

**P.S.**

Описание алгоритма бинарного поиска.
[image: Бинарный поиск]

Comment: Просто гляньте, у вас там high при очередном уменьшении выскакивает в -1 - что при беззнаковости превращается сами понимаете во что...

Comment: @Harry, так ведь в том и беда, что не должно быть такого в силу алгоритма.

Comment: Как говорит Кнут, почти никто не может сходу написать бинарный поиск и без ошибок.

Comment: @KoVadim, слышал(
Но всё равно действительно не понимаю, почему `high` становится отрицательным

Comment: Не должно - поэтому исправляйте **реализацию** алгоритма.

Comment: @Harry, самое интересное то, что если заменить модуль на составное число, то ошибка не выскакивает

Comment: Посмотрите на 

    `while (low <= high)`

Если нижний и верхний индексы совпадают - что вы *продолжаете* искать? А если `low` и `high` теперь равно нулю, что у вас получается?

Comment: @Harry, если честно,я пока не понимаю, что с этим делать, так как алгоритм именно так и работает...

Comment: @Setplus: Что значит "не должно быть такого в силу алгоритма"? В вашем алгоритме прописано черным по белому, что это "должно быть".

Comment: @AnT, я могу добавить в вопрос описание алгоритма, чтобы мне указали, где я неправ.

Comment: Добавил описание алгоритма + переписал немного код, чтобы он соответствовал алгоритму. Но всё равно ошибка вылетает.

Comment: @Setplus: В вашем описании алгоритма используется *знаковый* тип индекса. Это - ключевой момент. Вы же в своем коде использовали *беззнаковый* тип индекса, который ведет себя совсем по-другому. Потому и не работает. На самом деле беззнаковый тип - это правильно, но алгоритм под него надо подправлять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как я писал выше, Кнут говорит, что только процентов 10 людей могут написать рабочий бинарный поиск (статья на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/91605/)). Улучшу его высказывание - 90 процентов людей не могут написать бинарный поиск, даже видя его алгоритм и 99% не всегда умеют его применять правильно:)

Сам алгоритм так хитро написан и "заоптимизирован", то нужно очень аккуратно его использовать. Очень аккуратно. Одно неверное движение и компилятор все уничтожит. Но об этом позже.

Самое первое, что нужно знать о бинарном поиске, это то, что он работает только с отсортированным списком. Если массив не отсортирован, то результат абсолютно не предсказуем. (Не, можно конечно подогнать так массив, что бы результат был правильный, но зачем?)

**Отсортируем**

Для этого вначале нужно определить компаратор. Классический компаратор просто вычитает числа, так как числа беззнаковые. Я написал его "в лоб"

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
    uint64_t x1 = *(uint64_t*)a;
    uint64_t x2 = *(uint64_t*)b;
    if (x1 == x2) return 0;
    if (x1 > x2) return 1;
    return -1;
}
```

он возрващает 0, если равны и +1 и -1, если больше/меньше

теперь, перед вызовом поиска, вставим сортировку

```
qsort(cArr,T,sizeof(uint64_t), cmpfunc); // это сортировка
for (i = 0; i < G_SIZE; i++) {  // эта строка есть
```

Теперь код уже даже будет работать, но очень редко. Так как там есть случайные числа, то оно будет через раз.

Теперь переходим собственно к алгоритму поиска. В нем есть 3 (ТРИ!!!) ошибки.

Первая просто опечатка.

```
left = right + 1;
```

и все, левая часть больше правой... там должен быть middle вместо right.

Вторая ошибка из за отступов.

вот этот код

```
if (left > right)
        return  -1;
```

должен  быть внутри цикла while. Это опечатка или нет - не знаю.

А третья ошибка сложнее. И половина ее прячется в коде, который приведен в второй ошибке. Дело в том, что код рассчитывает на то, что right может стать меньше нуля. Но он (упс) беззнаковый. И после вычитания очередной единицы будет очень большим... По хорошему нужно заменить на знаковый тип и все должно заработать, но мы легких путей не ищем. Поэтому, пришлось добавить костыль в алгоритм. Он мне не нравится, но что поделать. Ниже приведена "полностью исправленная функция поиска".

```
uint64_t contains(uint64_t num,uint64_t *arr,uint64_t left,uint64_t right)
{
    uint64_t middle = 0;
    while (1) {
        middle = (left + right) / 2;
        if (arr[middle] > num) {
            if (middle == 0) return -1; // <== это костыль
            right = middle - 1;
        }
        else if (arr[middle] < num)
            left = middle + 1;
        else 
            return middle;
        if (left > right)
            return  -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Потрясающий ответ, спасибо! Согласен на то, что у меня две опечатки и одна ошибка, которую я в силу неопытности вряд ли бы сам обнаружил :)